# How do I keep a running Subtotal/Sum in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I know this is probably a super simple question, but I have no clue how to word it in Google so I could find out on my own. 
I have a spreadsheet in Excel that's basically a shopping list:

```
Apples--------$1.00             

Bananas-----$2.25

Carrots-------$1.75...
```

What I need to know is how to create a running subtotal in the next column that will tell me what the total is after adding each item. Which would make the spreadsheet now look like this:

```
Apples--------$1.00--------$1.00      

Bananas-----$2.25--------$3.25     

Carrots-------$1.75--------$5.00...
```

At the end of the day, I'd **like** to be able to just add a new item and price and have it calculate the running subtotal on it's own, but I'd settle for it just being able to handle the existing list as I've shown. Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 8):

A simple way of doing it is to use a `SUM` formula with an absolute starting address but an ending address that changes as the formula is copied with series expansion.

Assuming that the prices are in column `B` and that they start at `B1`, place `=SUM($B$1:B1)` in the first cell of the running total column. Then select the cell so that you see the gripper at its bottom right. Grab that and drag down until there are as many entries in the running total column as there are in the item price column.

Excel will automatically adjust the formula so that it sums from the top of the item price column down to the same level as the current cell in the running total column. The dollar signs in the formula prevent the starting cell from being adjusted when you extend the series by dragging, but the ending cell is automatically adjusted because it has no dollar signs on its address (it is a relative address).

Comment: Beaten on time, I would have suggest the same way to solve this! +1 :-)

Answer (score 4):

BenN's excellent answer is probably how I would handle this, but here's another idea just to give you a structure that may work in some other specific situation:

Assuming that the prices are in column B and the running total is in column C:  place `=B1` in the first cell of the running total column, *C1*. Then place `=C1+B2` in cell *C2.*  This adds the new value to the previous running total.  Select cell *C2* so that you see the small black square gripper at its bottom right. Grab that square and drag down until there are as many entries in the running total column as there are in the item price column.  (Double-clicking on that little square should auto-filldown as well.)

Comment: This is by far the simplest solution. (And it's what I have been doing for a decade.)

Answer (score 1):

A more complex, but alternative way to do it, with a slight twist:

```
A       B           C         D E
Item    Price    Amount   $2.50 Sum
Apples  $1.00   2.5     
Bananas $2.25           
Carrots $1.75
```

The formula in D1 is `=SUMPRODUCT(B2:B4;C2:C4)`

---

You may also add `=COUNTIF(A:A;"<>")-1` in D2, type `# of items listed` in E2 (to the right of D2), then change D1 to:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(INDIRECT("B2:"&CELL("address";OFFSET(B2;D2-1;0)));INDIRECT("C2:"&CELL("address";OFFSET(C2;D2-1;0))))
```

... and the list update will end up be as simple as typing in the item, the price and any amount.
As "# of items..." gets updated, the price and amount in the columns beside the new item will be included in the sum in D1.

**How it works:**
`COUNTIF()` in D2 will tell how many rows there is with filled in rows; that is: it includes the title row, which is "removed" from the sum by `-1` at the end.
The use of `OFFSET()` will produce a "reference" to the cell D2 rows down from B2 (and C2), adjusted by "-1" to not include the cell below the last item.
The reference will then be turned into text by `CELL()` so that it is possible to append it to `"B2:"` with `&`...
With the produced text string, `INDIRECT()` will create what `SUMPRODUCT()` needs to fulfil its task.
A piece of cake, isn't it? ;-)